# How to work with App.Path

Tags: vb6

Well i made these code in VB6 but when i run it , the Vb said me Path not found , can anyone help me, here is my VB code:

```
MkDir App.Path & "\users\" & Splice(2)
Open App.Path & "\users\" & Splice(2) & "\pass.txt" For Append As #1
Print #1, Splice(3)
Close #1
Open App.Path & "\users\" & Splice(2) & "\list.txt" For Append As #1
Print #1, "" 'we have to put something into the buddy list
                 'so well put nothing ;)
Close #1
Open App.Path & "\users\" & Splice(2) & "\info.txt" For Append As #1
Print #1, "" 'we have to put something into the buddy list
                 'so well put nothing ;)
Close #1
Open App.Path & "\ipreglog.log" For Append As #1
    Print #1, inip
Close #1
```

Thanks

Comment: There's a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293368/vb6-open-file-for-append-issue-path-not-found

Comment: Try adding a breakpoint to see what path it's actually tryign to use.  
You can also make it less error prone by assigning the path to a variable and using that:
    
    BasePath = App.Path & "\users\" & Splice(2)
    MkDir BasePath
    Open BasePath & "\pass.txt" For Append As #1

Comment: yup , exactly , i have problem with \users\ patch

Comment: Well , my problem has been solved but no i get Path/File access error

Answer (score 3):

MkDir is not recursive so it requires the immediate parent to exist.
Try ensuring that the Users directory exists first:

```
MkDir App.Path & "\users\"
MkDir App.Path & "\users\" & Splice(2)
```

Comment: Well , my problem has been solved but no i get Path/File access error

Answer (score 2):

Erm, probably the path does not exist. You need to investigate further to find the exact problem.

1. Use a breakpoint (or a MsgBox) to pause the code and tell you *exactly* which path it is trying to open.
2. While you have the code paused, go to Windows Explorer and check whether the path exists.
   a. Check for spaces in the pathname.
   b. Check that all the directories exist. MkDir only makes one directory at a time, it requires the immediate parent to exist (as Deanna says).

You are writing to files underneath App.Path. Watch out for [virtualisation of Program Files](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2006/Oct/08/Folder-Virtualization-in-Windows-Vista-). Windows prevents programs from writing to `Program Files` and its subdirectories by secretly writing to a virtual folder instead.

Comment: Well , my problem has been solved but no i get Path/File access error

Comment: What's the exact path that it's trying to access? Is it the correct path. Check whether the directory exists, check the security permissions on the directory and file. Can you edit a file on that path in another program, like Notepad (for example)?

Comment: Look at these code :'BasePath = App.Path & "\users\" & Splice(2)
MkDir BasePath
Open App.Path & "\users\" & Splice(2) & "\pass.txt" For Append As #1
Print #1, Splice(3)
Close #1
BasePath = App.Path & "\users\" & Splice(2)
MkDir BasePath
Open App.Path & "\users\" & Splice(2) & "\list.txt" For Append As #1
Print #1, ""
Close #1
BasePath = App.Path & "\users\" & Splice(2)
MkDir BasePath
Open App.Path & "\users\" & Splice(2) & "\info.txt" For Append As #1
Print #1, ""
Close #1'